# How can I jump to a ViewController lower in the Navigation-Tree

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I've got a NavigationController to navigate through some ViewControllers.
It is embedded in a TabbarController.

From **View A** it is possible to show **Modal VC** (which handles imported files)

[image]

Now I want to do this:
When a new file comes in (via "Open in..."), in AppDelegate following function is called:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, openURL url: NSURL!, sourceApplication: String!, annotation: AnyObject!) -> Bool
```

1. Within this function I want jump directly to **Modal View**
2. Now the User can go back from **Modal View** to **A** showing all the Back- and Tabbar-Buttons which would have been created during a "normal" walk through the Navigation-Tree

Any help would be great!

Comment: "From View A it is possible to show Modal VC"... Not trying to sound snarky at all, but why do you think it wouldn't be? Just trying to understand...

Comment: It is possible to show that VC modally. This is the given structure to navigate through the app. But now (as an addon) I want to jump directly (after app-launching) to that modal VC. I want to simulate (however) the clicks the user would have done if he would have navigated to this point manually

Comment: Oh, I see. You can't insert vc's in the stack behind your first vc, so you don't really want to "jump directly to Modal View" if you want to be able to go back to A. You'll have to go to A then Modal View, but if you do so using completion blocks and no animation you may be able to make it appear as if you're jumping directly to the Modal View.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I could not solve that problem but did a workaround. Now my Navigation is a bit different but it works.